# How does Int get converted to BigDecimal?

Tags: scala

I am not able to understand how scala converts Int to BigDecimal in scala.

```
val a : BigDecimal = 1
```

The above statement should have ideally thrown a compilation error , however it compiles fine. Could anyone please explain how does this happen in scala?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this question lies in the BigDecimal object which has an implicit method that converts Int to BigDecimal.

From the source code of scala

```
object BigDecimal extends scala.AnyRef with scala.Serializable {
// all other methods
  implicit def int2bigDecimal(i : scala.Int) : scala.math.BigDecimal = { /* compiled code */ }

}
```

Please let me know if this answers your question.